# remove out of office assistant from another user (outlook 2007/exchange 2003)

Tags: exchange-2003

Is it possible to remove/change the out of office message for a user in an exchange environment w/o logging in as them.  I have administrative privileges.

Answer (score 2):

Use Outlook Web Access and you can turn it off in the options.

JR

PS You can open the users mailbox with https://server/exchange/useralias, where "useralias" is the users Exchange alias. You should be able to open this with the administrator username and password.

Ha, I beat Evan to it this time (by 6 seconds :-)

Comment: In a stock Exchange 2003 install the idiotic "Deny / Receive As" permissions at the top of the organization will prevent that, though.

Comment: I have always been able to do this on a stock Exchange 2003 config.  He's just logging into the account, not setting up Receive as another user.

Comment: @moshen: "Receive As" permission controls the ability to open a mailbox. Somebody has to have modified your security from stock if you're seeing that behaviour. Have a look here under the heading "Permissions to access mailboxes": http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa998117(EXCHG.65).aspx  or here http://support.microsoft.com/kb/821897/  This was a change starting in Exchange 2000 that caused headaches for me. It's worse in Exchange 2007 because service packs put back the stupid ACEs.

Answer (score 1):

If you remove the silly "Deny / Receive As" permissions at the "Organization" level you can access their mailbox with your "Administrator" credential using OWA and just turn the feature off.

By default in Exchange 2003, though, members of several groups (Administrators included) can't access any ol' user's mailbox because of these "Deny / Receive As" permissions. I've removed these permissions for years because I think it's perfectly legitimate for an Administrator to access user mailboxes as necessary for troubleshooting, etc.

You should probably be mindful of your corporate privacy / security policies as you go about doing this.

Comment: Perfect.  Thanks.  Luckily I had a blackberry enterprise user I could go in and do this with w/o removing that default acl.

Comment: +1 to your comment for thinking of using the BES user... heh heh...